# Arreglar codigo para tomar fecha y hora local

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una consulta con `javascript` para poder obtener la fecha y hora local de mi portatil pero mi problema es que me toma el mes como 4 y no 04 que es el que necesito, por favor me podrian ayudar, muchas gracias y aqui les muestro el codigo para poder obtener la fecha y hora

```
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var mes = (m < 10) ? +0+ + m : m;
d = (d.getFullYear()+'-'+mes+'-'+d.getDate()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds());
console.log(d);
```

si miran en consola me lo toma por ejemplo a mi: `28-4-2018 10:32:50` pero necesito el 4 como 04, agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 3):

Te doy una opcion un poco fea pero funciona. Le añadi un "0" delante del mes. Espero te sirva.
Tambien tienes Moments http://momentjs.com/ donde encontraras informacion para el tema de fechas.

```js
var d = new Date();
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var mes = (m < 10) ? +0+ + m : m;
d = (d.getFullYear()+'-'+'0'+mes+'-'+d.getDate()+''+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds());
                console.log(d);
VM656:5 2018-04-28 18:16:56
```

También puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera algo más bonita utilizando las comillas invertidas "``" y colocando cada variables dentro de "{}" con los pesos delante ($):

```js
var d = new Date()
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
var mes = (m < 10) ? +0 + + m : m;
d = (d.getFullYear()+`- 0${mes}-${d.getDate()} ${d.getHours()}:${d.getMinutes()}:${d.getSeconds()}`)
console.log(d)
```

Comment: Yo recomiendo momentjs para TODO. El objeto `Date` es un desastre.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en lo de momentjs, date tambien use, pero no hice mas que empezar en el mundo javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacerlo con toISOString().

```js
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toISOString();
document.write(n);
```

> Fuente: [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com)

O podrias usar el que se encuentra en este Post [Convert ISO date to international date type javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891974/convert-iso-date-to-international-date-type-javascript)

```html
<html>
<script>
  var myDate = new Date();
  var thisMonth = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), 1);
  var nextMonth = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth() + 2, 0);

  console.log("Formatted date start: " + formatDate(thisMonth));
  console.log("Formatted date end: " + formatDate(nextMonth));

  function padLeft(n){
    return ("00" + n).slice(-2);
  }

  function formatDate(){        
    var d = new Date,
        dformat = [ d.getFullYear(),
                    padLeft(d.getMonth()+1),
                    padLeft(d.getDate())
                    ].join('-')+
                    ' ' +
                  [  padLeft(d.getHours()),
                     padLeft(d.getMinutes()),
                     padLeft(d.getSeconds())].join(':');
     return dformat
  }

</script>
</html>
```

> Fuente: [Convert ISO date to international date type javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891974/convert-iso-date-to-international-date-type-javascript)