# ¿Cómo obtener una fecha en formato DD-MM-YYYY con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, date

Tengo el siguiente codigo que suma los dias ingresados en el input y los muestra pero la fecha la muestra DD-M-YYYY por lo que al guardarla en sql me manda error.

```
  <input type="text" id="fechaImagen" onclick="calculoImagen();" >
  <input type="number" id="frecuenciaDias" value="90" onclick="vaciarFechaSiguiente();" onchange="calculoImagen();" >
  <input type="text" id="siguienteImagen">
<script type="text/javascript">
var f = new Date();
fecha = f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() +1) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
document.getElementById('fechaImagen').value = fecha;
function calculoImagen() {
    tiempo = document.getElementById('frecuenciaDias').value;
    addTime = tiempo * 86400; //Tiempo en segundos
    f.setSeconds(addTime); //Añado el tiempo
    fechaSiguienteImagen = f.getDate() + "/" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
    document.getElementById('siguienteImagen').value = fechaSiguienteImagen;
};
function vaciarFechaSiguiente() {
  document.getElementById('siguienteImagen').reset();
}
</script>
```

¿como podria setear la fecha para que la muestre en este formato DD-MM-YYYY?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Te comento que lo puedes lograr del modo siguiente

```js
let date = new Date()

let day = date.getDate()
let month = date.getMonth() + 1
let year = date.getFullYear()

if(month < 10){
  console.log(`${day}-0${month}-${year}`)
}else{
  console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year}`)
}
```

Donde puedes notar lo siguiente:

> 1. Para obtener el día exacto hago uso de `getDate()`.
> 2. Para obtener el mes exacto le sumo un 1 al final pues estan en forma de arreglo y enero empieza en la posición 0
> 3. Para agregarlo un 0 a la izquierda a `month` y que se vea como pides solo lo metí en un `if` / `else` y comparé su longitud

Answer (score 3):

Asi da este formato "14-6-2018"

```
var f = new Date();
f.getDate() + "-"+ f.getMonth()+ "-" +f.getFullYear();
```

Comment: No lo retorna en el formato correcto. Por ejemplo: "28-8-2020" en vez de "28-09-2020".

Comment: @jsanmarb correcto pero solo `+ 1` y solucionado el problema y si lo de los ceros antes pues pásale condición a eso `month < 10` se agregue 0.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<html>
<script>
  var myDate = new Date();
  var thisMonth = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth(), 1);
  var nextMonth = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), myDate.getMonth() + 2, 0);

  console.log("Formatted date start: " + formatDate(thisMonth));
  console.log("Formatted date end: " + formatDate(nextMonth));

  function padLeft(n){
    return ("00" + n).slice(-2);
  }

  function formatDate(){        
    var d = new Date,
        dformat = [ padLeft(d.getDate()),
                    padLeft(d.getMonth()+1),
                    d.getFullYear()
                    ].join(' ');
     return dformat
  }

</script>
</html>
```

> Fuente: [Arreglar codigo para tomar fecha y hora local](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160058/arreglar-codigo-para-tomar-fecha-y-hora-local/160093#160093)

En ese post hice un respuesta. Aqui la acomodo lo que pides.

Answer (score 2):

Para obtener el mes los ceros correspondientes a la izquierda puedes usar la función `padStart(2,'0')`:

```
`${(date.getMonth()+1)}`.padStart(2,'0');
```

Esto también puedes aplicarlo para los días que tienen solo un dígito.

```
`${(date.getDate())}`.padStart(2,'0');
```

Ejemplo:

```js
 let date = new Date()
 let day = `${(date.getDate())}`.padStart(2,'0');
 let month = `${(date.getMonth()+1)}`.padStart(2,'0');
 let year = date.getFullYear();
 
 console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year}`)
```

Comment: Gracias, muy buena contribución,saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Hermano espero que te sirva

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            fecha = new Date();



            var meses = new Array ("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
            texto = document.getElementById("txtfecharevision");
            texto.value = fecha.getDate()+" de "+ meses[fecha.getMonth()] + " del " + fecha.getFullYear();

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando slice(-2)

```js
// using slice
let date = new Date();
let day = `0${date.getDate()}`.slice(-2); //("0"+date.getDate()).slice(-2);
let month = `0${date.getMonth() + 1}`.slice(-2);
let year = date.getFullYear();
    
console.log(`${day}-${month}-${year}`);
```