# datepicker entrega formato de fecha que no quiero

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

estoy trabajando con React con un [ESTE](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) datepicker

Defini el formato yyyy-mm-dd pero al parecer esto es solo de manera visual. Lo que necesito es solamente conseguir el año mes y día, pero lo que me trae es tambien la hora, minuto y segundo.

Hay alguna forma de obligarlo a que me entregue exactamente los 3 valores que necesito?

Este es el codigo que estoy usando actualmente

```
< MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils = { DateFnsUtils } >
    <KeyboardDatePicker
        autoOk
        value={from}
        onChange={(date: Date | null) => {
            setItemTableByDate({
                ...itemTableByDate,
                from: date, //Lo que seteo a mi state
            });
        }}
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        format="dd/MM/yyyy"  //Formato que necesito
        margin="normal"
        id="date-picker-inline"
        name="technical_review_duedate"
    />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider >
```

Si no se puede solo se me ocurre que en el onchange haga una funcion que tome una libreria como luxon, tome la fecha y solo saque esos 3 valores, pero la idea es que datepicker me lo entregue

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, lo que devuelve el `onChange` es el objeto `Date` en ese objeto tienes todos los datos que necesitas. El año, el mes y el dia, no hace falta que uses una libreria externa para obtener esos datos. Te comparto la documentacion del objeto `Date`
 https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: El tema es que el value como tu dices el es objeto date. Yo necesito solo yyyy/mm/dd y esto entrega tooodo. Además de eso, si es que utilizara el get day, full year y month tendría que meter logica ya que los dias y meses partes desde 0, entonces ya es complejo eso. Esperaba que datepicker pudiera retornarme directamente el tema y asi olvidarme yo de hacerlo a mano

Comment: Pero la documentacion del `DatePicker` especifica que `onChange` le va a pasar a tu callback un objeto Date, si quieres que devuelva un string con un formato específico puedes crear un fork del repo y contribuir con esa feature. Aquí puedes leer cómo contribuir con el proyecto material-ui-pickers -> https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/blob/next/CONTRIBUTING.md . Eso o puedes hacer una simple función que reciba el objeto Date y te devuelva el string que necesitas. (Seguramente está en stackoverflow) No creo que seas la primer persona en necesitar formatear una fecha. Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hay alguna forma de obligarlo a que me entregue exactamente los 3 valores que necesito?

La respuesta corta es no, **no puedes obligarlo a que te entregue los valores que necesitas**.

Por como especifica la documentacion de [KeyboardDatePicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/KeyboardDatePicker) el prop `onChange` le pasa a tu callback un objeto Date. Por lo que vas a tener que crear una función por tu parte para poder formatear la fecha a un string de tu conveniencia.

Puedes ver cómo formatear la fecha en la siguiente respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/181361/86914

> Hay alguna forma de obligarlo a que me entregue exactamente los 3 valores que necesito?

La respuesta larga sería que sí puedes "obligar" al componente a que te devuelva los  valores que necesitas. Para ello puedes hacer una contribución al repositorio de [material-ui-pickers](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers) con los cambios que necesitas y esperar a que tu cambio llegue a un release, o bien si es muy urgente, podrías crear un fork del repo y usar tu propia versión. Esto segundo sería posible ya que la [licencia](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers) que tiene el repo lo permite.

Si quieres saber como contribuir puedes leer la [guía de contribución](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-pickers/blob/next/CONTRIBUTING.md) del repo.